# How to write JS function that returns a Q library promise with correct value?

Tags: javascript, q

```
function prepareParams(user) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    var params = _.pick(user, 'email', 'password');
    _.extend(params, {
        grant_type    : 'password',
        client_id     : 'client_id',
        client_secret : 'client_secret'
  });

  return deferred.promise;
  deferred.resolve(params);
}
```

I want to use this function in chain of promises but it doesn't return the value.

```
prepareParams(userParams))
.then(function(params) {
    // ERROR!!! params == undefined
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to write synchronous code using promises, no. But the code you've shown should basically work, if the callback is encountered it'll be called with an object not `undefined`.

Comment: You've got some syntax errors in your `then` invocation, and mostly your problem seems to be that you try to  `resolve` the deferred after the `return` - so it's never executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to write a synchronous Promise, but you have to make sure you call the `deferred.resolve(params)` first. Once you `return` from a function, no other remaining code in the function will run.

```
function prepareParams(user) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();

  var params = _.pick(user, 'email', 'password');
  _.extend(params, {
    grant_type    : 'password',
    client_id     : 'client_id',
    client_secret : 'client_secret'
  });

  deferred.resolve(params);
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Note that the only change is to switch those two lines around.

You also have a syntax error in your callback, the closing parens `)` should be at the end of the whole thing and not the `prepareParams` call. This is because you are intending to call `.then` on the results of `prepareParams`. Here's what it should look like:

```
prepareParams(userParams)
  .then(function(params) {
    // should work now :)
  });
```